# Reliable connectors for digital sensors

Tags: sensor, connector, reliability

I have designed a data collection device which is mounted on a moving vehicle. Is there any recommended connectors that can survive high vibrations for digital sensors?

Comment: Other than the ones that screw on?

Comment: Amphenol, either threaded or twist-lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Delphi Connection Systems](http://www.delphi.com/) has some great products that are designed for automotive applications and some are waterproof. Mouser carries them. Eg. their Weather-pak series. They're used for pressure sensors and such like.

You can also use military-style circular connectors or M8, and some of the Lemo connectors are very good.

[image: http://ca.mouser.com/images/delphiconnectionsystems/images/12059595hs.jpg]